# ASP.Net WebApi MapHttpRoute works on Visual Studio but doesn't work on IIS in a WebForm application

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, webforms, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a this simple route in `Application_Start` of `Global.asax`:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("MyApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
```

and this is the folder path of controller and the page that wants to use from controller:

[image]

when i run the project in the visual studio, it works fine, but when i publish the application on iis, i'm see this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**UPDATE**

This is the content of my controller:

```
public class VideoController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(long id)
    {
        try
        {
            // some code here
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, e);
        }
    }
}
```

and i call this controller by put the html5 video tag in `default.aspx` under this path:

`WebContent/pages/web/default.aspx`

```
<video controls="" preload="auto" class="uk-width-1-1">
    <source src="/api/video/3" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

how can i solve this problem.

Comment: what's the code in your controller, did you put route attribute like [Route("api/getContacts")]

Comment: @uowzd01, i'm updated my question, please help me, this is very critical for me.

Answer (score 0):

This line could be the issue.

```
<source src="/api/video/3" type="video/mp4">
```

If you have hosted the application on IIS using Visual Studio itself, it will typically host it under a web application under your default website and your url will look like this http://localhost/youappname/

try changing your url to

```
<source src="/yourAppnameinIIS/api/video/3" type="video/mp4">
```

Its worth a shot, if you haven't tried it already.

Answer (score 0):

set `path="*."` and `verb="*"` in your `web.config` file.

Comment: where should i put these configs? could you write the complete tag with attributes?

Comment: `<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*." 
        type="SampleHandler, SampleHandlerAssembly" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>`

Comment: i'm added this configuration but when run the project this error occurred: `HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.`

Comment: can you show me your web config code that have recently added?

Comment: you need to add verbs and path only where your integrated version declare.

Comment: this is my web.config file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8npWo6XrlQ-MVFGeGZXX0R2Slk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76179/discussion-between-rasool-ghafari-and-jaimin-soni).